# Simple Form with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm struggling.

Im trying to setup devise with bootstrap and simple form.

I noticed that my config has two simple_form files. One is simple_form.rb and the other is simple_form_bootstrap.rb.

Is that correct? It's odd because they both have some of the same fields, that are completed differently.

I'm having real difficulty rendering error messages in my devise forms. They do not display. I cannot find why. I wonder I having two config files for simple form is part of the problem.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure here but maybe you should try "rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap". Since Devise does not add bootstrap styles automatically. Per this link  - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Simple-Form-with-Devise.